# Ensure consistent time indexing in statsmodels predict

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to fit an AR(1) model to a Pandas time series and project forward. The data is annual with each year starting at 1 April. When I use `statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.predict` to forecast from the estimated model the output is a Pandas time series with the annual forecasts centred on 31 December.

Code:

```
mod1 = sm.tsa.AR(ser['1972-01-04':'2007-01-04'], freq='A')
res1 = mod1.fit(order=1)
fcast1 = res1.predict('2007-01-04', '2018-01-04')
print fcast1
```

Output:

```
2007-12-31     988.121031
2008-12-31    1035.640294
2009-12-31    1081.584720
...
```

Can I get the predict method to create a time series indexed on 1 April, or do I have to re-index the forecast series after creating it? I'd like to be able to compare it to other series in the dataframe so the indexing is quite important.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: excitingly enough, the second line gives me a segmentation fault (!)

Comment: Hmmm, runs for me on pandas 0.10.1 and statsmodels 0.4.3. As a complete novice at Stack Overflow, could it be that I've omitted something important in my question?

Comment: My mistake, it runs ok. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at the moment, but you should be able to in the next release. The fix should be fairly trivial. The pandas time-series stuff is relatively new compared to when I wrote the TSA infrastructure, and I just haven't had a chance to catch up. Too much to do.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/319

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just wanted to make sure I want missing something really obvious before I bodged it.

Comment: No problem. I'm pretty sure you could add a pandas offset to the result to recenter on the dates you want, but obviously that's suboptimal. You can follow that issue if you want. I hope to fix it soon. Just got bumped up my priority list as long overdue.